# Complex clustering using generalized estimating equations

Tags: r, regression, logistic, correlation

I am studying judicial decision making. I have coded a large number of cases, each of which was heard by three judges randomly selected from a judge pool. I have coded whether each judge's vote was a conservative or liberal vote, and I have each judge's political affiliation. I want to see if a judge's party status predicts voting behavior. If each observation is a particular vote for a judge, then the outcome is binomial (liberal or conservative vote) and the primary predictors are that judge's political affiliation and one or more variables representing the number of conservatives out of the additional two judges.

I believe that my observations may be correlated in two ways: I have three observations for each case (because three judges vote in every case), and I have many observations for each judge. Observations for the same case may be correlated, as may be observations for each judge. I am not particularly interested in learning about any one judges in particular. What I really care about is: as a general matter, do conservative judges tend to vote more conservatively.

I think I want to use generalized estimating equations to assess the data so that I can account for these potential correlations, but I'm only finding examples for how to do this with software for one type of correlation. Do you agree that GEE is the right approach, do you think a different approach might be better, and how do I do this on R or a similar software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of two-way correlation has been studied by multiple independent people (including me).  Two useful published references are by [Miglioretti and Heagerty](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/15208201/) and by [Cameron, Gelbach and Miller](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25800796).  I have a [blog post](https://notstatschat.rbind.io/2021/09/18/crossed-clustering-and-parallel-invention/) here, including a link to R code. Cameron et al

The basic idea is that you get the same sort of sandwich estimator as with longitudinal/clustered data, but the middle of the sandwich is
$$\sum_{(i,j)\sim(i',j')} U_{ij}U_{i',j'}^T$$
where $(i,j)\sim (i',j')$ if the pairs share *either* index and $U$ is the estimating function.

In more generality, you add up $U_s$ and $U_t$ for pairs where you don't know *a priori* that the correlation is zero, and you get a consistent estimator as long as that's an asymptotically vanishing fraction of all pairs.

Comment: Thank you, I believe I should be able to take it from here!